# Data Table with Different Column Number Per Row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following code to display a table where first row contains 8 columns to show data. Once user clicks on the row, it will expand the next row to show all details in a a segment/panel. The issue now when I am using a plugin to add sorting functionality. The issue complains on why I have 8 columns in one row, and only one column in second row.

```
                    <tr id="row-<?php echo $_id?>" class="trigger <?php echo $_rma->getIsEven() ? 'even' : 'odd'?>">
                        <td class="small-1"><a class="action" href="#" onclick="return false"><span></span></a></td>
                        <td class="small-1"><?php echo $_rma->getIncrementId() ?></td>
                        <td class="small-2"><?php echo $_rma->getOrderIncrementId() ?></td>
                        <td class="small-2"><?php echo $_orderDate ?></td>
                        <td class="small-2"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_rma->getCreatedAt(), 'short', true) ?></td>
                        <td class="small-2" id="status-<?php echo $_id ?>"><?php echo $_rma->getRmaStatusName() ?></td>
                        <td class="small-1" id="reason-<?php echo $_id ?>"><?php echo $_rma->getRmaReasonName() ?></td>
                        <td class="small-1"><?php echo $_rma->getTotalQty()*1 ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="info-<?php echo $_id?>" style="display:none">
                        <td id="container-<?php echo $_id?>" class="small-12 no-pad" colspan="12">
                            <span class="urma-info-loader"><?php echo Mage::helper('udropship')->__('Please wait, loading RMA information...')?></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The error is as explained here: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4
I cannot seem to find other way other than having empty hidden columns to complete the count. I tried using colspan but also still getting the error.

Comment: Even with that colspan you have a different number of columns - I count 8 in the first row, so why do you have a colspan of 12?

Answer (score 0):

Datatable requires the same number of column on each row. There's a hacky way, you may hide the rest of unwanted row.

jsfiddle.net/9wppdkpe/

UPDATED:

Unfortunately, the sorting fuction has to be disabled, otherwise the toggle function won't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    // This has to be disabled otherwise, the toggle fuction won't work
    "ordering": false,
    rowCallback: function(row, data) {
      if ($(row).hasClass('target')) {
        if ($(row).find('td').not('.colspan').length > 0) {
          $(row).find('td').not('.colspan').remove();
        }
        $(row).find('.colspan').attr('colspan', 5);
      }
    },
  });
  $('#example').on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    $(this).next('.target').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.target {
  display: none;
}

.colspan {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
      <th>Heading 4</th>
      <th>Heading 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>Click me 1</td>
      <td>Click me 1</td>
      <td>Click me 1</td>
      <td>Click me 1</td>
      <td>Click me 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="target">
      <td class="colspan">Colspan row 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable">
      <td>Click me 2</td>
      <td>Click me 2</td>
      <td>Click me 2</td>
      <td>Click me 2</td>
      <td>Click me 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="target">
      <td class="colspan">Colspan 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is best to always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Eky. I am thinking of switching from toggling a row to using a modal to display the details of that row which will contain customer order details (shipping address, items, etc). Is there any argument why not to use modal in this case? Are modals considered a user friendly component and is a good practice?

Comment: Or if there is any alternative solution to such problem. I am looking to show a row of order summary and once clicked, I show all details.

Comment: I think modal is a better option here, as you don't have to force having a colspan in the table row here, so the code is much more cleaner, and reduce potential of buggy code. In order to implement modal action here, you just need to use ajax (onclick event) to load the data and populate them into your modal, then display the modal.